# insert from ordered select results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure runs every day and does simple work. How it works:

1. Getting actual '*tree*' of entities
2. Fill temporary table
3. Select ordered data from temporary table
4. Fill another table with 3 columns - *here I have a problem becouse i can't insert from ordered select*.

So. The here the procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateQueueAccountOrder]
    @dtUtc datetime
AS
BEGIN
    delete from dbo.[Feedback.QueueAccountOrder] -- clean dest table

    create table #TempTree
    (
        [Total]         int,
        [AccountCode]   nvarchar(20),
        [AccountName]   nvarchar(512),
        [Utc]           float,
        [CityCode]      nvarchar(50),
        [CityName]      nvarchar(128)
    )

    -- getting actual flat tree
    insert into #TempTree exec GetActualFeedbackQueueTree @dtUtc

    declare @total int;
    select @total = count(*) from #TempTree
    print 'total nodes ' + str(@total)

    select distinct tA.AccountCode, tA.AccountName, tA.Utc, tC.CityCode, tC.CityName
    from #TempTree tC
    left join #TempTree tA
    on tA.CityCode = tC.CityCode
    order by tC.CityName,tA.AccountName
END
```

Another table is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Feedback.QueueAccountOrder](
    [QOrder] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Code] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Utc] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The target is to fill this table with result of last selection of stored procedure. Not what `QOrder` need to be an order from select (1, 2, 3, 4 etc), `Code` and `Utc` come from selection results too.
So. How to solve it? Thanks!

ps. Stack:
T-SQL, MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: Why not add an insert statement into the stored procedure `insert into Feedback.QueueAccountOrder(QOrder,Code,Utc) select ... from #TempTree tC
    left join #TempTree tA
    on tA.CityCode = tC.CityCode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your goal correctly - you need something like this:

```
insert into dbo.Feedback.QueueAccountOrder
(
    QOrder,
    Code,
    Utc
)
select
    row_number() over(order by T.CityName, T.AccountName),
    T.AccountCode,
    T.Utc
from
(
    select distinct tA.AccountCode, tA.AccountName, tA.Utc, tC.CityCode, tC.CityName
    from #TempTree tC
        left join #TempTree tA on tA.CityCode = tC.CityCode
) as T
```

I'm not sure about field mapping in final select, because it is not clear from question - should it be AccountCode or CityCode - it's up to you.

But key idea remains the same - first select your distinct values and then insert data from select using `row_number` as enumerator of your resultset.